# Run python process in docker in linux screen in detach mode

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have written Dockerfile for my python application.

Requirement is :

- Install & start mysql server.
- Run the application in screen in detach mode.

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update OS
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip screen npm vim net-tools
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install mysql-server python-mysqldb

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY ./src/nsd.ini /etc/

RUN pwd
RUN cd /usr/src/app

RUN service mysql start  
RUN /bin/bash -c "chmod +x src/run_demo_app.sh && src/run_demo_app.sh"
```

Below is the content of bash script

```
$ cat src/run_demo_app.sh

$ screen -dm bash -c "sleep 10; python -m src.app";
```

The problem is Mysql doesn't start. I need to start it manually from container.

Also, the screen becomes dead and application do not start. Manually running the script works fine.

Answer (score 5):

So this is a understanding gap and nothing else. Note below issues in your docker file

**Never use service command**

```
RUN service mysql start
```

Docker doesn't use a init system. So never use a `service` command inside docker.

**Don't put everything in same container**

You should not put everything in the same container. So `mysql` should run in its own container and python in its own

**Use official images**

You don't need to re-invent the wheel. Use official images as much as possible. You should be using `mysql` and `python` images in your case

**Use docker-compose when multiple services are needed**

In your case since you are requiring multiple services, use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

**No need to use screen in docker**

Screen is used when your want your process to be running even if your SSH disconnects. So that in not needed in docker. If you run your `docker run` or `docker-compose up` command with an additional `-d` flag then your container will automatically be launched in background

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Lalwani for the edit and the answer. I am aware of the docker-compose and running 'mysql' as separate container. But my requirement is to run in single container, that's why I tried to start 'mysql' as service. Thanks to pointing for the reason of failing. I do want to use screen and see no reason why the screen can't be used. More importantly I want to understand why its failing during start of container.

Comment: @nebi, see if this article helps http://tarunlalwani.com/post/deploying-code-inside-docker-images-statically-dynamically/. There is a section for using supervisord, which you should be using in your case